# Classifying PDEs as linear or nonlinear

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm confused as to whether the following PDEs are linear or not:

(A) $u_{t}-u_{xx}+xu=0\\$

(B) $iu_{t}-u_{xx}+u/x=0\\$

(C) $u_{x}(1+u_{x}^{2})^{-1/2}+u_{y}(1+u_{y}^{2})^{-1/2}=0\\$

(D) $u_{t}+u_{xxxx}+\sqrt{1+u}=0\\$

For (A), I don't think it's linear because if you subtract $xu$ from both sides, and divide by $u$, you get terms that are no longer linear in $u$ on the LHS.

For (B), I don't think it's linear for the same reason as I thought (A) was not linear.

For (C), I don't think that it is because of the $u_{x}^{2}$ and the $u_{y}^{2}$ terms, but the $-1/2$ powers are making me second guess that.

For (D), I don't think that it's linear because if you subtract $\sqrt{1+u}$ from both sides, and then square both the right and left-hand sides, you'll wind up with nonlinear powers of the partials on the LHS.

Could somebody please tell me whether for each of these I'm right or not? And if not, could you please explain the reason to me?

I'm trying to learn PDEs on my own, and these are introductory problems from Strauss' book.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

A PDE, in your variables, $f(u,u_x,u_t,u_{xx},u_{tt},u_{xt},\ldots;x,t) = 0$, is said to be non-linear if $f$ is non-linear with respect to $u$ *and* to its partial derivatives. For example, $f$ is linear in $u$ if $f(\lambda_1 v + \lambda_2 w, \ldots;x,t) = \lambda_1 f(v) + \lambda_2 f(w)$, for every scalar $\lambda$ and functions $v$ and $w$.

In a), since there are no non-linear relations involving $u$ or its partial derivatives, you can conclude that it is linear. Follow this to conclude that b) is linear and c) and d) are not.

Cheers!

Comment: I guess I was confused b/c I thought the inhomogeneous part on the RHS had to be a function only of the independent variables and not $u$, so I thought you had to try to get rid of any $u$s on the RHS, which would then wind up introducing nonlinear relations of $u$ on the LHS. I see now that that's not how it's done thanks to you! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome! Here you have some well known examples of linear PDE's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation and non-linear PDE's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-linear_partial_differential_equations